# Drag and drop to Desktop / Explorer

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, drag-and-drop, explorer

Following my scenario.

I got an Application which loads a Filestructure (Folders, Files) from a Database into a WPF ListView. Now I'd like to grab a file from this ListView, drag it over my Desktop (or some open explorer window) and drop it there. Basic Drag and Drop, nothing fancy. This sounds like a "standard" function for a windows application - but google won't help.

So how can I achieve this? Interops?

Thanks

**Edit**: Thanks for the solution, I still had to do some googling. [Here's my complete solution](http://codebrewery.blogspot.com/2010/06/drag-and-drop-files-from-wpf-listviews.html).

Comment: it would be appreciated if you posted your complete solution as an answer here.

Comment: I tried your example but it wont compile, DragDrop is unknown. Do I need to add a reference or something ?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`DragDrop.DoDragDrop` can do this as long as you pass it an appropriate `DataObject`.

First copy the files somewhere.  You can use `System.IO.Path.GetTempPath()` if you don't have anywhere better.

Next create a string array containing the full paths to the files and do the following:

```
string[] paths = ...;
DragDrop.DoDragDrop(this, new DataObject(DataFormats.FileDrop, paths),
                    DragDropEffects.Copy);
```

It is actually possible to do this without pre-copying the files but that gets into some complicated IDataObject interactions, so unless your files are potentially very large and aren't already in the filesystem I would try this method first.

Comment: I know this is a very old thread, but could you expand on your statement about "unless your files are potentially very large"-part? I'm trying to do exactly that. Have a DragDrop functionality, which downloads the file when dropping it somewhere.

Comment: How to do the same with DragAndDrop folders?

Comment: @Argnist Same as files. Folder are treated as Files.

Comment: @Ray-Burns Copying a large file to temp location might take a lot of time. Is there any other way to achieve this and resolve `IDataObject` interactions at the same time? Please have a look at my [Question Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32725514/unable-to-drag-file-to-windows-explorer-from-a-wpf-listview) also.

Comment: @AishwaryaShiva but they are not copied to explorer as files. I do DragDrop and nothing happens.

Comment: @Ray-Burns where does the DragDrop object comes from ? I tried your example but DragDrop is not a know class. Do I need to add a reference ?

Comment: It should be noted that having the data in an array is crucial even if you have only one file!