# Can we drop a file in windows explorer from WPF window?

Tags: wpf, drag-and-drop

I have a treeview that shows the current file system. I want to add functionality to enable dropping files into windows explorer. If I drag any of the node of my treeview and drop it on any of the window of Windows explorer then the file will be copied to that location. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# / WPF / .NET - Drag and drop to Desktop / Explorer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3040415/c-wpf-net-drag-and-drop-to-desktop-explorer)

Answer (score 1):

First read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742859.aspx) about how to implement drag and drop in WPF.

The read [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/explorerdragdrop.aspx) for some information about what explorer expects when you drop in it.

Then ask new questions if you still have any.