# Drag control outside main window

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop

It is more common to drag files to an application than to drag files from an application to directory in windows. In my wpf application I have a list of files. I will like to enable the user to drag those files (files are custom user control with an image and label) to the desktop for example. Is it possible to do that? Moreover I will like to use the default functionality of windows. That is if I drag the file to a new disk, partition then I will like the file to be copied. If the directory happens to be on the same partition as the file I will like to move that file.

**Edit**

I found lots of great examples such as [this one.](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/Explorer_Drag_Drop.aspx) and the one that SvenG mentioned in the comments section of this question.

none of those examples work when I need to transfer large files. The mouse cursor and application does not let me interact until the copying or moving of the file is done. I tried ruining that on a separate thread and I have not been able to do so.

Comment: Have a look on this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3040415/drag-and-drop-to-desktop-explorer
Only thing you have to figure out is detecting the drop target

Comment: Thanks for the link. I started a bounty because I need to be able to do it with large files... this question is a duplicate of that question. maybe I should deleted. sorry