# How to drag remote item from WPF onto desktop?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, drag-and-drop

In FileZilla, I can select a file on a remote site and drag it onto my desktop.  ***After*** I 'drop' the file on my desktop, FileZilla starts streaming the file.

I want to achieve similar functionality using WPF - is this possible and how can it be done?

Below is a snippet which shows how to drag a local file to the desktop using it's file path.  My scenario is different in that the file is not physically available when DragDrop.DoDragDrop is called.

```
//FileDetails holds information about where the file is downloaded from.
FileDetails fileDetails = (FileDetails)listView.ItemContainerGenerator.
    ItemFromContainer(listViewItem);

DataObject dragData = new DataObject(DataFormats.FileDrop, fileDetails);
DragDrop.DoDragDrop(listViewItem, dragData, DragDropEffects.Copy);
//At this point control goes to the OS.
```

Ideally I'd like to detect the 'drop' event with information about where the drop occured. Another option might be to pass a StreamWriter in to DoDragDrop() and write the bytes into it as they are received.

Comment: Are you trying to achieve something like that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3040415/drag-and-drop-to-desktop-explorer?

Comment: @Guillaume - that answers the question about how to do drag/drop a file that already exists, but unless I'm wrong, I don't think it covers the more tricky issue of streaming the file after the file is dropped.

Comment: @bobsmith833 Indeed, you're right...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this:

[Creating something from nothing [Developer-friendly virtual file implementation for .NET!] - The blog of dlaa.me](http://dlaa.me/blog/post/9913083)

I think that does what you require.

Comment: It crashes running the sample code from Visual Studio, but works well when executing the .exe directly.  Thanks.