# How to create an icon that can be dragged to explorer or skype to save/send a file?

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop, skype

I'm working on a tool that generates output that I'd like the user to be able to conveniently send to Skype or other running applications rather than simply saving it if required.

Back when I used Acorn's RiscPC, the recommended style of the 'Save As' feature was a small dialog with an icon that represented the file, that you could drag to a folder to save, or drag to another application to send it to that app rather than saving it.

Right now, users need to save the file, then find the file in Windows Explorer and drag it to Skype from there. Sure I could easily add a 'Show in folder' icon, but it would be much neater to simply drag it straight to Skype.

Anyone know how to do this, or if it's been done before I can have a look at?

I should emphasize, I'm not specifically talking about dragging stuff to Skype, I could look at the Skype API for that, I'm talking about simulating a drag generally, as if it were a file dragged from explorer.

Comment: You need to save the file somewhere, initiate your drag-drop with that file and skype will do the rest..

Comment: [Creating something from nothing (Developer-friendly virtual file implementation for .NET!)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2009/10/26/creating-something-from-nothing-developer-friendly-virtual-file-implementation-for-net.aspx) shows how to drag virtual content in C#. Whether Skype recognizes virtual content is another matter entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using WinForms, [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14059/Drag-and-drop-cut-copy-and-paste-files-with-Window) is a CodeProject article that shows you bi-directional drag and drop to and from Explorer/your application. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3040415/drag-and-drop-to-desktop-explorer) for WPF.

Hope this helps!