# "Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component" when trying drag and drop an image to Skype c#

Tags: c#, com, drag-and-drop, skype

I'm trying to drag and drop an image from my C# app to Skype and the following error occurs: Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
With other applications like Word, Excel works fine.

```
                        // Find the data behind the ListViewItem
                        DashboardItem item = (DashboardItem)listView.ItemContainerGenerator.
                            ItemFromContainer(listViewItem);

                        DragDropEffects returnedEffect = DragDropEffects.None;
                        dragging = true;

                        switch (item.Type)
                        {
                            case DashboardItem.ContentType.IMG:
                                BitmapSource realFile = new BitmapImage(new Uri(item.Content));
                                if (realFile != null)
                                {
                                    using (MemoryStream bitmapAsStream = Utils.BitmapSourceToStream(realFile))
                                    {
                                        if (bitmapAsStream != null)
                                        {
                                            using (MemoryStream dib = new MemoryStream())
                                            {
                                                    dib.Write(bitmapAsStream.GetBuffer(), 14, (int)(bitmapAsStream.Length - 14));
                                                    DataObject dragData = new DataObject(DataFormats.Dib, dib);
                                                    //Error next line
                                                    returnedEffect = DragDrop.DoDragDrop(listViewItem, dragData, DragDropEffects.Copy);
                                                    bitmapAsStream.Close();
                                                    dib.Close();
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                break;
```

I would like to repproduce the same bahavior as Windows Explorer when dropping an image to Skype. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you drop an image from Explorer to Skype, the file is being sent. As far as I understood your code, you're dragging an image object, not a file.

If you would like to send a file from your file system, [use this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3043436/126995).

If however you'd like to create the file in runtime without saving it to the file system, you could implement a virtual file, as described in the "Virtual file" section [of this guide](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2009/10/26/creating-something-from-nothing-developer-friendly-virtual-file-implementation-for-net.aspx).

Comment: Thank you for your hels Soonts, I just changed the drop data and worked!