# Hide some values in XAML GridViewColumn if they met a condition

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, gridviewcolumn

I have a `GridView` with some elements binded to my object. The value where I'm working is this:

```
<GridViewColumn x:Name="DataGridLastEdit" Header="Last Edit" Width="150px" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding lastEdit}" />
```

`lastEdit` is a `DateTime` type, but for some elements its empty and it display **1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM** (it can change based on computer time format setting), making a pretty ugly effect.

I just want to hide it for element who don't have a valid date, but I'm pretty new to XAML and I can't to that. I read about using Converters but I always do some errors writing it and can't even try if it works, how can I do that?

Comment: Yes, you should use a binding converter. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.converter.aspx) is an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [ValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx):

```
public class EmptyDateCoverter: IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if(value is DateTime)
        {
            if((DateTime)value == DateTime.MinValue)
            {
                 return "";
            }
        }
        return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        //We don't need convert back
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Create a resource for the converter for example in the control's resources (conv is the [alias for the namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms747086%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) where the converter is defined )

```
<conv:EmptyDateCoverter x:Key="EmptyDate" />
```

and then apply the binding in this way:

```
<GridViewColumn x:Name="DataGridLastEdit" Header="Last Edit" Width="150px" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding lastEdit, Converter={StaticResource EmptyDate}}" />
```

Comment: i know this is not the right way to ask this but, do you have any idea on how to solve this other question? Grazie mille! :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20971127/get-file-path-for-drag-n-drop-file-on-windows-explorer