# Drag and drop to Windows Media Player

Tags: c#, .net, windows, drag-and-drop, explorer

I have already implemented drag and drop in the way described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3040415/drag-and-drop-to-desktop-explorer), so my code looks like

```
string[] paths = ...;
DragDrop.DoDragDrop(this, new DataObject(DataFormats.FileDrop, paths),
                    DragDropEffects.Copy);
```

But this implementation works only for explorer. What should I change to allow drop to Windows Media Player?

Comment: This certainly works not only for Explorer. I don't have WMP but it works fine for VLC, IRfanView, FireFox and others..

Comment: Year, you are right. It works not only for Explorer. But I need it to work with WMP.