# Drag & Drop file from listview to windows explorer?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, drag-and-drop

I have a bunch of files listed within a listview, and I want to know is it possible to drag and drop the files to Windows Explorer? If so how?  I only seem to find examples of the other way around.  Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3040415/drag-and-drop-to-desktop-explorer

Answer (score 8):

So here's what I did.

First off, in your listview, create an event handler for ItemDrag.

Then the following..

```
    private void listView_ItemDrag(object sender, ItemDragEventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> selection = new List<string>();

        foreach (ListViewItem item in listView.SelectedItems)
        {
            int imgIndex = item.ImageIndex;
            selection.Add(filenames[imgIndex]);
        }

        DataObject data = new DataObject(DataFormats.FileDrop, selection.ToArray());
        DoDragDrop(data, DragDropEffects.Copy);
    }
```